# Mazda5 - any way to disable "recirculation off while in defrosting mode" feature?

Tags: ac, mazda, hvac

I have Mazda5 2013, trying to fix an annoying issue - every time I set air to blow towards windshield, recirculation is turning off - and there is no way to turn it back on if selector is still in the "defroster" or "defroster and floor vents" position

The manual says "*When selecting either defroster mode, the air conditioner and fresh air mode are automatically turned on by the system. This helps defrost the windows more efficiently by dehumidifying the air*."

The problem is - I don't care if defrosting will take a little longer with recirculation turned on ( so I don't have to inhale exhaust fumes)  - I can live with that

It's not just about defrosting - when my windshield is getting misty while I am on a freeway, I have no choice but to switch air to "defrost" position and recirculation is getting turned off automatically

So, here is the question - **is there any way to manually override that "feature" and be able to set recirculation even while defroster mode is selected?**

Comment: Don't know about your Mazda, but in most cars turning this off is not an option, short of completely rebuilding/re-engineering the HVAC system in your vehicle.

Comment: Welcome to new automobiles. Enjoy your stay! (I dread the day when I don't have control over stupid little things like this for absolutely no good reason).

Comment: I vaguely remember from my '83 Mazda 626 (which did allow this combination) that recirculation+defrost options together would slowly build up mist even on a windshield that was clear at the beginning. In other words, defrosting would not only _take a little longer_, but _would have opposite effect_. Admittedly, it could be slightly better with A/C.

Comment: My old VW Golf did this; workaround was to leave the air direction knob turned to just shy of defrost. Bonus points: it refused to run the A/C when it was too close to freezing, which in New England often left me completely fogged up and stuck in my driveway.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the apparent contradiction of it, using the AirCon and heater to defrost the windows is a very much quicker to clear the windows on a cold start. The Mazda is one of many cars that use this as a device to enable good visibility for a quicker drive away from starting.

Comment: The OP is worried about recirculating exhaust gasses. Even in their question it is stated, "*I don't care if defrosting will take a little longer with recirculation turned on ( so I don't have to inhale exhaust fumes) - I can live with that...*" With this in mind, I'm not sure how your statement provides an answer.

Comment: I take your point. But how will he draw in exhaust fumes, presumably, sitting on his drive waiting for the windows to clear before driving on the road.

Comment: It's not just about defrosting - when my windshield is getting misty while I am on a freeway, I have no choice but to switch air to "defrost" position and recirculation is getting turned off automatically

Comment: @AllanOsborne ... What goes on in the garage should stay in the garage :P

Comment: I endorse the maxim 'What goes on in the garage...' In the UK it means you support and defend your colleagues, but I dont know what in means in the American version.